# PHP an MySQL - Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show a value from a database table through PHP echo. The MySQL result is a double (10, 2).

```
<?php $link = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', '*******', '*******', '*******');
                     if ($link->connect_errno) {
                        die('Failed to connect to MySQL: (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
                     }
                    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
                    $result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND active=1");
                    $numrows = $result->num_rows;
                    if($numrows == 0 || $numrows > 1)
                    {
                        $link->close();
                        session_destroy();
                        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=**************">';
                        exit;   
                    }
                    else if($numrows == 1)
                    {
                        //$sid = $result(8);
                        echo '<strong>this is my string in which i want to show the result in' . $result(8) . 'rest of the string';}?>
```

Line where the error is show is the echo line (in the end). Can anyone point me out to what I am doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: $result is a link to the query (resource), you have to fetch the results first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$result` variable is a [MySQLi Result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). You want to get a row from that result set. To do that, use fetch_assoc. This will give you an associative array with all of the fields of the table as keys.

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['username'];
echo $row['whatever'];
```

EDIT: It may be valuable to note that you are susceptible to the following security risks: [SQL injection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEsQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&ei=kViBUfKNO4GFyQG-uYDgDA&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ&bvm=bv.45921128,d.aWc), [cross-site scripting](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting&ei=tliBUbLpF8nrygHl7oHQBg&usg=AFQjCNF8gcMuXHACArbxvQ0vCgcPHMWSlg&bvm=bv.45921128,d.aWc), and Cookie tampering.

Comment: Since OP is using (8) they may want to `fetch_row();`

Answer (score 3):

you are calling `$result(8)` which is a method call in php. I think you meant

```
$dataRow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// collect whatever you need from the array $dataRow array
```

since PHP is an interpreted language you can do such things as assign a value to a variable and call that variable

```
$func = 'myFunc';
$func(); // will call the function myFunc
```

Comment: $result is a resource not an array

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result __object__. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access to an array value, you must use:

$result[8] and not $result(8)

Best regards!

Answer (score -1):

Look at this - $result(8) (last row). A variable can't have arguments. You probably wanted $result[8] (9th element in array).